# How to segregate logs by date in pm2?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I am using PM2 for a NodeJS server, I have some npm commands in the `package.json` file which call pm2 in either production or development mode as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "env NODE_ENVIRONMENT=development pm2-dev start ecosystem.config.js --ignore 'data'",
    "production": "env NODE_ENVIRONMENT=production pm2 start ecosystem.config.js"
}
```

When these commands are called, the `ecosystem.config.js` file uses either the node interpreter or the ts-node interpreter in production and development environments respectively.

```
const { mkdirSync } = require('fs');

var script = "";
var exec_interpreter = "";
var err_log = "";
var out_log = "";
var combined_log = "";
var date = new Date().toISOString();

if (process.env.NODE_ENVIRONMENT === 'production') {
    script = "dist/app.js";
    exec_interpreter = "node";

    mkdirSync(`./logs/${date}`, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
        if (!err) {
            err_log = './logs/' + date + '/error.log';
            out_log = './logs/' + date + '/output.log';
            combined_log = './logs/' + date + '/combined.log';
        } else { console.error(err), process.exit(1) };
    });
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENVIRONMENT === 'development') {
    script = "src/app.ts";
    exec_interpreter = "ts-node";
}

module.exports = {
    apps: [{
        name: 'Hyve',
        script: script,
        exec_interpreter: exec_interpreter,
        max_restarts: 10,
        error_file: err_log,
        out_file: out_log,
        log_file: combined_log,
        time: true
    }]
}
```

As you can see the logs are also directed to the log files in a production environment. But, when the script runs in the production environment, the log files do not go into separate folders as I intend them to, instead they are written to in the root of the logs folder. This will help visualize what I mean:
Intended result:

```
logs
├── 2021-05-30T06:56:31.477Z
│   ├── combined.log
│   ├── error.log
│   └── output.log
└── 2021-05-30T06:56:56.512Z
    ├── combined.log
    ├── error.log
    └── output.log
```

Actual result:

```
logs
├── 2021-05-30T06:56:31.477Z
├── 2021-05-30T06:56:56.512Z
├── combined.log
├── error.log
└── output.log
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: The path seems fine, but can you share the code where you are writing in just for one log? It seems to work file on my local. Check the path correctly when you are writing the log.

Comment: The application just uses `console.log | console.error | console.warn` as necessary. PM2 then captures and writes the logs to the specified files. Read more [here](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/log-management/#ecosystem).

Comment: It seems the ecosystem config file is not being taken correctly, it is by default sendin g the empty paths to the file.

Comment: What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();
var dat= date.getDate()+"-"+date.getMonth()+"-"+date.getFullYear();


fs.mkdirSync(`./logs/${dat}`, { recursive: true });

fs.exists("./logs/${dat}",(err) => {
    
    if (!err) {
        console.log('in');
        err_log = './logs/' + date.toISOString() + '/error.log';
        out_log = './logs/' + date.toISOString() + '/output.log';
        combined_log = './logs/' + date.toISOString() + '/combined.log';
    } else { 
        
        console.error(err)};
        console.log("created succesfully");
});
```

over here i have separated main folder with just the date and log file with ISOString which will help you to take time as well.

Comment: I tried using `\`logs/${date}/whatever\``, but it didn't work. Also, I am using `Date().toISOString()` in the initial definition of `date` as I require the date and time to be displayed in the logs.

Comment: ok got it mkdirSync doe'nt have a callback in it's method for ref
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_options
i am editing my ans

Comment: also, i noticed you have the variables, but files will not be created unless you create them,you can use "fs.open" method for this.
eg.
    var fs = require('fs');

fs.open('mynewfile2.txt', 'w', function (err, file) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('Saved!');
});